# Unknown column in field list - Subquery not finding parent variable

Tags: mysql, subquery

The following query

```
SELECT
LocationID,
a.Country,
ISO2,
Region1,
Region2,
Region3,
Area1,
a.City,
a.ZIP,
a.Lat,
a.Lng
FROM AWE_Locations a,
(SELECT PropVidID,
    Latitude,
    Longatude,
SQRT(POW(69.1 * (Latitude - a.Lat), 2) + POW(69.1 * (a.Lng - Longatude) * COS(Latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS Distance FROM AWE_Propvids c
)
as x

WHERE
a.ZIP  LIKE '9021%' and
a.Country = 'US'

HAVING
x.Distance <= '100'

ORDER BY
a.Country,
Region1,
Region2,
a.city,
ISO2,
a.zip

ASC Limit 15
```

returns the error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'a.Lat' in 'field list'
```

Why cant the subquery use the variable from the parent query in this case?
I have tried various combinations to try and fix this, but have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the following part of the select as if you're defining another Table (that you call `x`):

```
(SELECT PropVidID,
    Latitude,
    Longatude,
SQRT(POW(69.1 * (Latitude - a.Lat), 2) + POW(69.1 * (a.Lng - Longatude) * COS(Latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS Distance FROM AWE_Propvids c
)
as x
```

when this Table is defined, which `a.Lat` should be used ?

The way to fix it is have the "outer" query run, and use its results when you run the second query on `AWE_Propvids`.

It should look something like:

```
SELECT 
a.LocationID,
a.Country,
a.ISO2,
a.Region1,
a.Region2,
a.Region3,
a.Area1,
a.City,
a.ZIP,
a.Lat,
a.Lng,
SQRT(POW(69.1 * (Latitude - a.Lat), 2) + POW(69.1 * (a.Lng - Longatude) * COS(Latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS Distance 

FROM AWE_Propvids c,

(SELECT
LocationID,
a.Country,
ISO2,
Region1,
Region2,
Region3,
Area1,
a.City,
a.ZIP,
a.Lat,
a.Lng
FROM AWE_Locations a

WHERE
a.ZIP  LIKE '9021%' and
a.Country = 'US') as a

ORDER BY
a.Country,
a.Region1,
a.Region2,
a.city,
a.ISO2,
a.zip

ASC Limit 15
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** Why cant the subquery use the variable from the parent query in this case?

**A:** Because that subquery is an inline view. MySQL will run that query and create a temporary table, the "derived table" (as MySQL calls it) is a row source for the outer query. The inline view query has to be run *before* the query that references it.

A correlated subquery can be used in a WHERE clause, a HAVING clause, an IN clause, or in the SELECT list, but it isn't valid in the FROM clause, as an inline view query.